# kprobe_events fetch-args works for x86 but not arm64

Tags: linux-kernel, trace, perf, kprobe, tracepoint

I wanted to get `do_sys_open` filename argument as string. For this i added kprobe following [kprobetrace.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/kprobetrace.txt). A simple probe which gives filename as hex works for both `x86/arm64`.

```
x86: echo 'p:myprobe do_sys_open filename_string=%si' > kprobe_events
arm64: echo 'p:myprobe do_sys_open filename_string=%x1' > kprobe_events
```

However changing probe to get string for file name works on `x86` but not `arm64`(ie cannot get string representation `filename_string=(fault)`)

x86:

```
echo 'p:myprobe do_sys_open filename_string=+0(%si):string' > kprobe_events
output: 
adb-30551 [001] d... 4570187.407426: myprobe: (do_sys_open+0x0/0x270) filename_string="/dev/bus/usb/001/001"
```

arm64:

```
echo 'p:myprobe do_sys_open filename_string=+0(%x1):string' > kprobe_events
output: 
netd-4621  [001] d...  8491.094187: myprobe: (do_sys_open+0x0/0x24c) filename_string=(fault)
```

To check if i was using arm ABI correctly i tried setting probe using `perf`. 
The probe created by perf as seen from `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/kprobe_events` was similar

```
./perf4.14 probe 'do_sys_open filename:string'
/d/tracing # cat kprobe_events
p:kprobes/myprobe do_sys_open filename_string=+0(%x1):string
```

But perf probe was also failing (ie `filename_string=""`) in this case.

```
./perf4.14 record -e probe:do_sys_open -aR sleep 3
/data/local/tmp # ./perf4.14 script
perf4.14  4587 [007]  7490.809036: probe:do_sys_open: (ffffff8337060148) filename_string=""

   sleep  4588 [003]  7490.817937: probe:do_sys_open: (ffffff8337060148) filename_string=""
```

What would be the correct way to set `kprobe_events` for arm to fetch args as string? 
Am i using the ABI incorrectly?

Comment: Though the original issue on arm64 remains, i used below as workaround.
ie add trace-event somewhere inside function where function args is converted to local var. `+296` offset was taken from perf-probe -v
echo "p:myprobe do_sys_open+296 filename=+0(+0(%x19)):string" > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/kprobe_events

Answer (score 0):

On kernel version >= `4.20`, you can use `$argN` to fetch the `N`<sup>th</sup> function argument. From [kernel 4.20 kprobetrace.rst](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20/source/Documentation/trace/kprobetrace.rst):

```
 FETCHARGS  : Arguments. Each probe can have up to 128 args.
 .....
 .....
  $argN     : Fetch the Nth function argument. (N >= 1) (\*1)
```

Since the `filename` is second argument of `do_sys_open()`, you should give `$arg2` in the kprobe event, like this:

```
echo 'p:myprobe do_sys_open filename_string=+0($arg2):string' > kprobe_events
```

This should work on both `x86` and `arm64`.